# How i make mean and mode function in php and fill the null places

Tags: php, arrays, mean

Below is my array. I want to find **mean and mode**.

If the value is numeric then mean function run and found mean and put the result in null space and as well as if the value is string type then find the mode (most repeated value) and put this value in null space...

How can I make two functions to find mean and mode and how I judge the value are numeric and string then apply function and fill the blank spaces?

```
Array 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => one
            [2] => two
            [3] => two
            [4] => 

        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 5

        )
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: i make function mode and mean but i confused how i apply on it how i judge the value is numeric or string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the following statements and functions:

- [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php): to iterate over the elements
- [*empty()*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php): to detect the empty slot
- [*is_numeric()*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php): to know whether a value is numeric
- [`&`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php): not absolutely necessary, but this prefix makes it easier to modify an array while you are iterating over its elements.

Here is a function that fills the gaps with mean and mode:

```
function meanAndMode(&$data) {
    // repeat for each row in the data
    foreach($data as &$row) {
        $sum = 0;
        $mode = "";
        $numbers = 0;
        $numeric = true;
        $emptySlots = [];
        foreach($row as $index => &$value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                // remember where the empty slot(s) are, using "&"
                $emptySlots[] = &$value;
            } else {
                // all entries must be numeric to get the average,
                // otherwise they will be used as strings for get the mode.
                $numeric = $numeric && is_numeric($value);
                if ($numeric) {
                    // numeric: add up and count for 
                    // allowing mean to be calculated later
                    $sum += $value;
                    $numbers++;
                }
                // for numeric and non-numeric: keep count per string 
                $count[$value] = empty($count[$value]) ? 1 
                               : $count[$value] + 1;
                // keep track of highest recurrence count
                if (!$mode || $count[$value] > $count[$mode]) {
                    $mode = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        // Put result in empty slot(s). In case of numeric input,
        // the average needs to be calculated still:
        $result = $numeric ? $sum / $numbers : $mode;
        foreach ($emptySlots as &$emptySlot) {
            $emptySlot = $result; 
        }
        // avoid that the same slot is used in a next iteration that might
        // treat a row without an empty slot.
        unset($emptySlots);
    }
}
```

Here is how you would call it:

```
// test data
$data = array(
    array(4, 2, 3, null),
    array("one","two","two", null),
    array(8, null, 8, 5)
);
// apply function to fill in the blanks
meanAndMode($data);
// show result
var_export ($data);
```

The output is:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 3,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
    2 => 'two',
    3 => 'two',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 8,
    1 => 7,
    2 => 8,
    3 => 5,
  ),
)
```

Note that this function always calculates the mode, but if at the end it finds that *all* elements were numeric, it fills the gap with the mean, and ignores the mode. This way the function will work well when there is a mix of numeric and non-numeric data. In that case all will be interpreted as non-numeric.

If there is more than one empty slot, all of them will receive the result value.

Comment: Sir really no words i am really thankful to you really its very helping for me

Comment: sir its work but if null spaces are more then one then how calculated mean or mod put every null space please tell me

Comment: I updated my answer. Now the function will fill all the empty spaces with the result value.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I made a small correction in the `unset` statement near the end of the function. It needs to be `unset($emptySlots);` with an `s` at the end, because it must apply to the array, not a single element. Actually, I now think that statement is not necessary at all. You can even remove it.